# Is it possible to group user controls WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, user-controls, grouping

I have a project designing an industrial HMI.  We have developed a collection of Usercontrol's for graphics; pumps, pipes, blowers, etc. Each Usercontrol is set to fill one square on our grid for each separate display.

Example:

```
<IndustrialControlsLibrary:PipeCornerMM Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="12" Rotate="270"/>
<IndustrialControlsLibrary:SprayLarge Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="12"/>
<IndustrialControlsLibrary:PipeStraight Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="13" Rotate="90"/>
<IndustrialControlsLibrary:PipeEnd Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="14" Rotate="270"/>
```

So these four items are a collection of connected pipes that change color when a value is set in the control. Is it possible to group the 4 usercontrols, so in the code we can call setStatus() once and have it apply to all of them? Initially we were going to add each of them to a list or array programatically but it is really time consuming.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: You should read about MVVM, WPF was built with MVVM in mind and it make this kind of thing really easy/magic : every control would just bind to the same property containing the desired color.

Comment: "add each of them to a list or array programatically but it is really time consuming"? really? very strange.

Comment: Being a bunch of industrial controls engineers, our group has been lacking proper software design techniques.  Roger Leblanc, you sent me down a rabbit whole, I ended up re-implementing my entire program using MVVM and it has really changed our approach to writing our own code.  The data binding really does exactly what we needed, and has ended up eliminating a good deal of code. Thanks!!!